# Slice python data frame based on change in value or list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe that I want to slice into multiple dataframes based on the change in column values. The dataframe looks like:

```
                                               Image         Yaw  Sign
0   IMG_170705_121224_0148_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -41.299461  -1.0
1   IMG_170705_121226_0149_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.885353  -1.0
2   IMG_170705_121228_0150_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -38.424816  -1.0
3   IMG_170705_121230_0151_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -44.121506  -1.0
4   IMG_170705_121232_0152_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -43.348404  -1.0
5   IMG_170705_121234_0153_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -33.564381  -1.0
6   IMG_170705_121236_0154_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -22.381189  -1.0
7   IMG_170705_121238_0155_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -24.130825  -1.0
8   IMG_170705_121240_0156_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -36.879814  -1.0
9   IMG_170705_121242_0157_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -32.717499  -1.0
10  IMG_170705_121244_0158_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -55.632034  -1.0
11  IMG_170705_121246_0159_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -41.810268  -1.0
12  IMG_170705_121248_0160_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   -38.68877  -1.0
13  IMG_170705_121250_0161_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -38.238991  -1.0
14  IMG_170705_121252_0162_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -33.106453  -1.0
15  IMG_170705_121254_0163_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -25.821913  -1.0
16  IMG_170705_121256_0164_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   56.908508   1.0
17  IMG_170705_121258_0165_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif    48.51984   1.0
18  IMG_170705_121300_0166_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  114.620369   1.0
19  IMG_170705_121302_0167_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  106.544044   1.0
20  IMG_170705_121304_0168_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  105.703751   1.0
21  IMG_170705_121306_0169_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  111.010986   1.0
22  IMG_170705_121308_0170_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  100.446739   1.0
23  IMG_170705_121310_0171_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   87.035179   1.0
24  IMG_170705_121312_0172_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   93.275948   1.0
25  IMG_170705_121314_0173_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   84.998108   1.0
26  IMG_170705_121316_0174_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   97.052902   1.0
27  IMG_170705_121318_0175_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   99.751534   1.0
28  IMG_170705_121320_0176_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   97.002548   1.0
29  IMG_170705_121322_0177_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif    98.25058   1.0
..                                               ...         ...   ...
54  IMG_170705_121412_0202_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -71.117188  -1.0
55  IMG_170705_121414_0203_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -55.625908  -1.0
56  IMG_170705_121416_0204_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -49.295944  -1.0
57  IMG_170705_121418_0205_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -36.872471  -1.0
58  IMG_170705_121420_0206_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   -34.20092  -1.0
59  IMG_170705_121422_0207_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -34.930763  -1.0
60  IMG_170705_121424_0208_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -37.000858  -1.0
61  IMG_170705_121426_0209_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.504391  -1.0
62  IMG_170705_121428_0210_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -41.150524  -1.0
63  IMG_170705_121430_0211_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.845219  -1.0
64  IMG_170705_121432_0212_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   -39.10614  -1.0
65  IMG_170705_121434_0213_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -35.891712  -1.0
66  IMG_170705_121436_0214_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   -37.41824  -1.0
67  IMG_170705_121438_0215_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -34.713837  -1.0
68  IMG_170705_121440_0216_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -48.803596  -1.0
69  IMG_170705_121442_0217_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -44.784882  -1.0
70  IMG_170705_121444_0218_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -40.010029  -1.0
71  IMG_170705_121446_0219_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -42.793995  -1.0
72  IMG_170705_121448_0220_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -41.527176  -1.0
73  IMG_170705_121450_0221_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.461327  -1.0
74  IMG_170705_121452_0222_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.929741  -1.0
75  IMG_170705_121454_0223_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -40.532288  -1.0
76  IMG_170705_121456_0224_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif   -45.85107  -1.0
77  IMG_170705_121458_0225_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -41.356819  -1.0
78  IMG_170705_121500_0226_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -45.120956  -1.0
79  IMG_170705_121502_0227_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -49.955151  -1.0
80  IMG_170705_121504_0228_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -54.691364  -1.0
81  IMG_170705_121506_0229_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -47.738556  -1.0
82  IMG_170705_121508_0230_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -37.778706  -1.0
83  IMG_170705_121510_0231_GRE_vig_ortho_correct.tif  -39.388027  -1.0
```

The slices need to happen each time `Sign` changes from positive to negative or visaversa. The issue is that I have a multiple dataframes to slice, and each has  a different structure to the `Sign` column, so some dataframes could have 3 slices (as this one would), while others could have many more.

I can get the index values for the slices quite easily with:

```
for mid, group in itertools.groupby(image_list['Sign'], key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    length.append(len(list(group)))

index = [] # store the index values for splitting the dataframe
total = 0 # reset total value

for i in length: # loop through length values for each 'group'
    total = total +i # add each value to get compound index values
    index.append(total) # these are the index values to split the dataframe
```

which gives me `[16, 53, 84]` where `image_list` is the dataframe, but this list would then need to be applied as index values in a for loop of some sort. The following works fine but it's not adaptive (i.e. only suited to the structure of `image_list`).

```
df1 = image_list.iloc[0:index[0]]
df2 = image_list.iloc[index[0]:index[1]]
df3 = image_list.iloc[index[1]:index[2]]
```

**Therefore how can I slice the dataframe based on a change in value of the** `Sign` **column in a manner that will work for multiple dataframes?**

BTW: the result of the slice can be a `dict`, `list` or `dataframe`.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, your question comes after you have the indexes (i.e. `[16, 53, 84]`) in order to use that in a loop? Can the `df1`, `df2`... be elements of a list?

Comment: @xg.plt.py I can automate the collection of index values and the number of slices quite easily. The question is how to apply them an adaptive manner so that it will work for multiple dataframes with a different number of slices and different index values. Yes `df1`, `df2` can be elements in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a list where each element is a dataframe looping with the `index` list you already have.

If `len(index)==3`, taking into account how `index` is built means that there will be 3 dataframes to generate, so you actually need 4 delimiters. You can get them using `None` at the start of `index` (because the last row is already in `index`). Thus, the code posted should be modified to the following:

```
index = [None] # store the index values for splitting the dataframe, a 0 would work too
total = 0 # reset total value

for i in length: # loop through length values for each 'group'
    total = total +i # add each value to get compound index values
    index.append(total) # these are the index values to split the dataframe
```

Which will return a list containing `[None, 16, 53, 84]`. With this list, you can slice without problems at the edges:

```
df_list = [image_list.iloc[index[i]:index[i+1]] for i in range(len(index)-1)]
```

This takes advantatge that `a[None:i]` is equivalent to `a[:i]`  (also, `a[i:]` is `a[i:None]`).

Comment: @xg.ply.py seems to have worked a treat! I was playing around with the idea of `for i in index[:-1]:`, but like you said, the start and end of the range was trick in a for loop

Comment: should it be `df_list = [image_list.iloc[index[i]:index[i+1]] for i in range(len(index)-2)]` instead of `df_list = [image_list.iloc[index[i]:index[i+1]] for i in range(len(index)-1)]` to stop creating an empty dataframe at the end?

Comment: At 84 there is a sign change or there iis it the end of the array? If it is the end of the array, will it happen systematically? Now the slice edges are `[(None, 16), (16, 53), (53, 84), (84, None)]`, therefore, if the last one is empty, it must mean that 84 is the last row

Comment: 84 is the end of the dataframe

Comment: Will `index` always contain the end of the dataframe? If so, the final `None` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes the final value in `index` will always be the last value in the dataframe because of the way `total = total +i` is done and how `length` is calculated. So I can delete `index.append(None)` and change it back to `df_list = [image_list.iloc[index[i]:index[i+1]] for i in range(len(index)-1)]` and it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I missed that part. I will edit the explanation on the length of `index` and its relation to the slice boundaries

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column that is uniquely assigned to each change in sign event.

Some sample data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Image':list('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'),'Sign':[1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]})
   Image  Sign
0      x     1
1      x     1
2      x    -1
3      x    -1
4      x     1
5      x     1
6      x    -1
7      x    -1
8      x    -1
9      x     1
10     x     1
11     x     1
12     x    -1
13     x    -1
14     x    -1
```

Now use `cumsum()` and `shift` to find locations of a sign changes and assign this value back to the dataframe

```
df['groups'] = (df.Sign != df.Sign.shift(1)).cumsum()
```

Now we can `groupby` the column `[groups]`, and store the slices of the original dataframe in a list

```
frames = [frame for _,frame in df.groupby('groups')]
frames[0]

  Image  Sign  groups
0     x     1       1
1     x     1       1
```